# Table borders issue

Tags: html

I have created 4 search filters to display search result and i have created borders for tables. But i am having problem when i jst click on one filter and 3 extra empty rows opens up or when i am using 2 filters then 2 extra empty rows open up. How do i avoid this ? Below is my HTML code-

```html
<html>  
<head>  
<title>classroom</title>  
</head>  
<form action="retrieve1.php" method="GET">
    <select name="Grade">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Grade</option>
        <?php grade($db) ?>
    </select>

    <select name="School">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose School</option>
        <?php school($db) ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Team">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Team</option>
    <?php team($db) ?>
    </select>

    <select name="Students">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Students</option>
        <?php students($db) ?>
    </select>

   
    <input type="submit" style="width:100px" value="Find" />
</form>

<TABLE BORDER="30" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="3" BORDERCOLOR="#707070">


    <tr> 
      <th width="197"> <div align="center">FirstName </div></th>  
        <th width="197"> <div align="center">LastName </div></th>  
        <th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>  
        <th width="197"> <div align="center">City </div></th>  
        <th width="197"> <div align="center">State </div></th>  
        <th width="197"> <div align="center">Country </div></th>
         
       
        
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to disable the Placeholders and require all options before you can search.

```
<select name="Grade" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Grade</option>
    <?php grade($db) ?>
</select>
```

You can try to have all filters have a `disabled selected` option but not have a `required` value, like this

```
<select name="Students">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Students</option>
        <?php students($db) ?>
    </select>
```

I don't know if you're looking for something like this, but I think you should provide some more code because now it's just a simple form with some select inputs and a simple button for us. I know for a fact the first option would work if you require all filters, because than you have to select a option at each filter before you can do a search. The second option I don't know because I have not all of your code.